# ¿Cómo hallar la palabra más larga de una cadena en Kotlin?

Tags: android, funciones, kotlin

Estoy tratando de crear una función en Kotlin para que me devuelva la palabra más larga de una cadena, pero no doy con la tecla.

He probado con esto y tras darle muchas vueltas, sigue sin funcionar:

```
fun longerWord(words: String): String {
    var words = words
    var longerWordSize = 0
    var use = 0
    var longerWord = ""
    while (!words.isEmpty()) {
        words = words.trim() { it <= ' ' }
        use = words.indexOf(" ")
        if (use < 0) {
            break
        }
    }
    val cut = words.substring(0, use)
    if (cut.length > longerWordSize) {
        longerWord = cut
    }
    longerWordSize = longerWord.length
    longerWord = words.substring(longerWordSize + 1)
    return longerWord
}
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar por favor? Muchas gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `split` para dividir el `String` en una lista de palabras:

`val list = words.split(" ")`

Luego puedes trabajar sobre la lista aprovechando la potencia de Kotlin. Por ejemplo puedes ordenar la lista de palabras según su tamaño y luego tomar la última como la más larga:

```
fun longestWord(words: String): String {
    return words.split(" ").sortedBy { it.length }.last()
}
```

Ten en cuenta que podrían haber varias palabras con el mismo tamaño que la última, aquí estarías tomando solo esa.

Comment: Genial, lo voy a probar ¡muchas gracias!